Why do we take the maximum possible $X$?
I tried to apply the method I read here to calculate the square root of $529$. So first I write $(10X+Y)^2=529$, which means $100X^2 + 20XY + Y^2 = 529$. Now I have to choose $X$ such that $X^2 \le 5$, and the reason here is clear to me. But I have to choose the maximum value of $X$ with this property (in this case it is $X=2$). It's correct, since $\sqrt{529}=23$, but I don't get why it has to be the maximum possible value.

What happens if you don't choose the maximum possible value?

This should be trivial. Let $N = 10 X + Y$ where $X \in \mathbb{N}$ is an arbitrary whole number and $Y \in \{ 0, 1, \dots, 9 \}$ is a single digit. Observe that the number you are calculating is
$$\left\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{N^2}{100}} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{N}{10} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{10 X + Y}{10} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor X + \frac{Y}{10} \right\rfloor$$
Since $X$ is integral and $Y < 10$, this quantity is just $X$.

I don't get it. How does this imply that $X$ has to be the maximum possible value?

Because otherwise $Y > 10$, which is a contradiction.

If you don't use the maximum value then you are likely to violate base-10 conventions where each digit is expected to be in the set {0, 1, ..., 9}.

You have two integers $0\leq X,Y\leq 9$ such that
$$100X^2+20XY+Y^2=529.$$
Because $X,Y\geq0$ it is clear that $X^2\leq5$ and so $X\leq2$. If $X\neq2$ then $X\leq1$ which implies
$$529=100X^2+20XY+Y^2\leq 100+20Y+Y^2,$$
but this is impossible because $Y\leq9$.
